# show $ord(-1)=1$ in $K^*$ where $|K|=p^n$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-fields

Consider a finite field $K$ of order $|K|=p^n$. Denote $K^*$ the group of units.

1. Show that if $p=2$ then the $ord(-1)=1$ in $K^*$
2. Show that if $p\geq3$ then $ord(-1)=2$ in $K^*$

---

How do I approach this problem. I believe at first sight it looks like an easy problem. But I don't see how I know anything about the elements in the groups.
I will list below the things I do know about $K$ and $K^*$ (Not necessarily useful):

Since $K$ is a field I know that $K^*=K\backslash\{0\}$. I also know that a finite field has prime characterstic (But I don't think I know exactly what prime number $char(K)$ is). I know that $K^*$ has to be cyclic, but I don't think I know the order of $K^*$?
Lastly, I also know that the order of a group element divides the order of the group.
Can I use any of this information to gain information about the group elements?

Isn't it also very weird if $ord(-1)=1$ then $-1=1$, so $-1$ acts as the neutral element wrt. multiplication. But I thought that the neutral element was unique?
edit: Maybe it's not so weird. I guess it mean that the multiplicative identity is also it's own additive inverse. So it is still unique. So I guess $K^*$ would be isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^*$ when $p=2$.

Comment: If the field has order $p^n$ then clearly the characteristic is $p$, because no other prime divides the order of $K$. If the characteristic is $2$ then indeed $-1=1$, and this doesn't contradict the uniqueness of the multiplicative identity. Here $1$ and $-1$ are just the same element.

Comment: @Mark Thank you, I forgot about the rule that a prime number divides some number N iff it divides one of the factors in N. 
So the argument would go like this?: $K$ is a finite field and has prime characteristic, lets call it $p_1$. This mean that the (additive) order of 1 in $K$ is $ord(1)=p_1$. Since the order of a group element divides the order of the group, we know that $p_1 | p^n$. But since $p_1$ is a prime it has to divides one of the factors $\implies p_1 | p \implies p_1=p$. So $K$ has $char(K)=p$.

Comment: If $p=2$ we have $1+1=0 \iff -1=1$. This also implies that $(-1)^1 =1$ so $ord(-1)=1$ in $K^*$. If $p\geq 3$ then $-1\neq 1$ in $K$, so we would have $(-1)^2=1$ which is true for any rings (where $-1\neq 1$)? this implies  $ord(-1)=2$

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If $p\geq 3$ then $-1\ne 1$ but $(-1)^2=1$, so the order of $-1$ is $2$.